# Find recursive (circular) id in array of Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, angular, recursion, lodash, circular-dependency

```
users= [
{Id: 1, parentId: 2},
{Id: 2, parentId: 3},
{Id: 3, parentId: 4},
{Id: 4, parentId: 1}
]
```

I have an array of objects. How can I get the cycling Id return true if array had.

1-2
2-3
3-4
4-1

case: finally, **Id 1** **parentId** should not be **1**.

Comment: **parentId for an Id should not equal.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse the "tree" and keep track of all nodes' `Id` that you encounter. If you encounter a given `Id` more than once, display an error.

```js
  users = [
    { Id: 1, parentId: 2 },
    { Id: 2, parentId: 3 },
    { Id: 3, parentId: 4 },
    { Id: 4, parentId: 1 },
    { Id: 34, parentId: 34 },
  ]

  var ids = {}
  users.forEach(function (e) {
    if (e.Id == e.parentId) {
      console.log(`${e.Id} has same parent ${e.parentId}`)
    }
    if (ids[e.Id] || ids[e.parentId]) {
      console.log(`For id ${e.Id}, found duplicate parent ${e.parentId}`)
    }
    ids[e.Id] = true
  })
```